# Are there infinite square free integers $4x+1, 4x+2, 4x+3$

Tags: prime-numbers, square-numbers

Clearly, $4$ divides $(x)(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$

Likewise, if a prime $p^2$ divides $x$, $p^2$ does not divide   $(x+p)(x+2p)\dots(x+[p-1]p)$.

Does it follow that there are an infinite number of instances $4x+1, 4x+2, 4x+3$ that are square free?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59741/are-there-infinitely-many-triples-of-consecutive-square-free-integers) on mathoverflow.

Comment: Policy Question:  Is it appropriate to close a question here if it is a duplicate of a question on mathoverflow?

Comment: The generalized Bunyakovsky conjecture implies that there are infinite many positive integers $x$ , such that $4x+1,\frac{4x+2}{6},4x+3$ are all prime, which implies that the answer to this question is "yes".

Comment: @lulu I don’t think that there even is a feature to close as a duplicate of a MO question

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch  Nor do I....but the sites are so aligned that I would expect this to happen a lot.

Comment: @lulu quite frequently questions get cross-posted from here to the mathoverflow by the OPs or by other users/commenters. Mathoverflow and maths stackexchange are two different communities, one for the general public and the other for professional mathematicians, so it shouldn't be surprising if people here do not find or know of mathoverflow.